# Is the Voronoi region of a lattice symmetric around origion?

Tags: integer-lattices, vector-lattices

Assume an n-dimensional lattice. Is the Voronoi region of the lattice symmetric around origion?

In other word, is the following statement true? "if $x\in \mathcal{V}$ then $-x\in \mathcal{V}$" where $\mathcal{V}$ indicates the fundamental Voronoi region of the lattice.

Thanks,

Comment: yes, because the lattice is symmetric around the origin. It is an additive subgroup of $\mathbb R^n.$